# Plotting a circle using differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, circles

I was watching the MIT's SICP [lecture](https://youtu.be/dlbMuv-jix8?t=2074) where the lecturer talks about plotting a circle using a differential equation like this:

$\frac{dx}{dt} = -y$

$\frac{dy}{dt} = x$

$x(t+\delta t) = x(t) - y(t).\delta t$

$y(t+\delta t) = y(t) + x(t).\delta t$

There is a corresponding code in `scheme` as well which implements this algorithm:

```
(define (circle x y)
  (plot x y)
  (circle (- x (* y dt))
          (+ y (* x dt)))
```

Can someone explain the intuition behind this? Does it actually draw a circle?

Comment: No, but it approximates one by drawing one point and then following the tangent for a short distance and then plotting that point. The problem is that actually the distance from the center grows a little with each iteration. So after you complete a rotation you will not be exactly at the start point.

Comment: Thanks, @Ian. Is there a name for this algorithm? I just wanted to know why the rate of change of x and y w.r.t time is `-y` and `x` respectively.

Comment: @Nishant: Well, what are the derivatives of $x(t)=\cos t$ and $y(t)=\sin t$? Regarding the name of the algorithm, it's just Euler's method for the system of ODEs $\dot x=-y$, $\dot y=x$.

Comment: You may want to use the symmetry and use the `plot` call to actually draw 8 points $(\pm x,\pm y)$ and $(\pm y,\pm x)$ in all sign combinations, then the error of the Euler method does not have too much time on the $45°$ segment to introduce visible errors.

Comment: From $\frac{dx}{dt} = -y$ and $\frac{dy}{dt} = x$, we can infer $x^2 + y^2 = C$.

Comment: Are you struggling understanding the system of DE's or the code that you provide?

Comment: @Rumplestillskin, the system of DE's. I understood the code (maybe because I have a programming background and this is nothing more than adding and multiplying :-)) but not the intuition behind it. I am much better now after the above comments! I need to learn more DE to be familiar with all this.